# Loop on datatable after deleting columns in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to delete rows from a datatable that have an empty or null cell, at the same time I check if a column has empty cells exceeding a percentage, if it's the case I drop the whole column. I tried proceeding like so:

```
 private DataTable CleanData()
        {
            var dt = BindData(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            for (var j = dt.Columns.Count-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                short count = 0;
                for (var i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString())) continue;
                    count++;
                }

                var percentage = count * 100.0 / dt.Rows.Count;
                if (percentage > 10)
                {
                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(j);
                    textFile.Text += " " + j + " ";
                }
            }

            dt.AcceptChanges();

            for (var j = dt.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            for (var i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString())) continue;
                dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            }

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            return dt;
        }
```

I loop a first time over the datatable cells, then check the percentage of empty cells in a column and if it exceeds 10% I delete that column, then I loop a second time and this time delete each row that has an empty cell, but on the second loop I get an error message  (`System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException`) when it reaches a deleted column index, even though it's supposed to loop on a datatable where those columns aren't there.
[image]
Any clue where I messed up ?
Edit: I made the changes proposed but still getting the same error

Comment: You should maybe call AcceptChanges inside the loop or use Remove instead of Delete.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem with a simple table of just 3 columns and three rows. However there is an error in the loop over the rows. The exit condition should be _i >= 0_ not _i > 0_

Comment: When deleting from an array always start at the end and move towards the beginning : for (var j = dt.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)

Comment: Right but this can't explain the exception related to a deleted row.

Comment: @Crowcoder the part where I use delete was working fine (because I started there then I added the loop that checks the % on a column.

Comment: @Steve I changed that too , nice catch, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that too but still same error..

Comment: Remove entire column : dt.Columns.Remove(dt.Columns[j]);  The row index 'i' is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I THINK you are running into is an unexpected side-effect of your loop checking % and deleting columns.  You are starting with the 0-index column (1st column). Checking and then deleting if empty.  Do it in reverse... start with the LAST column and work back to 0 and here is why.

Say you start with a table of 3 columns, so your loop counter is intended to to 0, 1, 2.  First cycle through, loop counter 0.  You determine data good, no delete.  Counter = 1 (2nd column).  Determine it needs to be removed due to % empty.  Now you delete column[1].  This moves what WAS column[2] and now becomes column[1] and your counter now advances to 2.  You never checked what WAS the third column.

If you did in reverse, you start at column[3], check it, find its ok (or not, dont care).  Now down 1 to column[2] and determine to remove.  So it gets deleted and column[3] is now column[2].  Now you check column[0] and finish no problem.

You are already doing this when checking the ROWS (starting at the end and working back).  Same principle applies.

As for your loop on deleting the ROW, I would invert your loops.

```
Outer loop per ROW (last row first, working back)
{
   Inner loop per COLUMN
   {
      if any single column qualifies to delete the row
      {
         dt.rows[i].Delete();
         break;  [break out of the column checking loop]
      }
   }
   [ continue with each ROW]
}
```

Since your existing outer loop is per column, if you process column 1 and delete row 5, then get to column 2 and try to delete row 5 again, that is your failure.

By checking all columns for a single row FIRST and getting out as soon as one qualifies for deletion, you are done with that row and never need to consider looking at any other columns.  Move to the next row for processing.

Comment: It made sense when you said it I didn't think about starting with last column there too, but even though I tried reversing the loop I still get the same error.

Comment: @Isumairu, revised answer, please review

Comment: thanks a lot, looping on rows first is more practical actually and it worked with my code when I used the `if` condition like you did.